# Change style of chapter headings in report class document

Tags: sectioning, formatting, numbering, report

I'm using that kind of page numbering:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\begin{document}
\part{Part name}
...
\chapter{Chapter name}
...
\section{Section name}
...
\subsection{Subsection name}
\end{document}
```

In chapter section it gives this result:

[image]

But I would like to achieve different chapter formatting, like this:

[image]

Is this is possible without changing the report class of the document?

Comment: You have the `titlesec` package for that.

Comment: @Bernard,thanks, could you please write the code? I'm not that talented to do this by myself.

Comment: Your question, as stated, is about the sectional headings and their formatting, not about the page numbering, right?

Comment: Regarding the `titlesec` package (which is a nice and also the standard tool to change the formatting of sectional headings) there is plenty of examples available here on TeX.SX. You can find it easily through the search engine. For instance I myself answered a few questions with specific sectioning design guidelines with `titlesec`. (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151029/changing-formatting-for-section-headers/151032#151032) Maybe this will help you to figure out how to bodge together the three required lines of code. If not please let us know!

Comment: @Ruben, yes, I have mistaken the name of the topic. Thank for answer, I will try.

Answer (score 1):

*-appearance `titlesec`*

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
  \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
    {\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter name}
...
\section{Section name}
...
\subsection{Subsection name}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I know that this is for experienced users really easy. I would need to read a tones of documentation to achieve that result. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome! In case of `titlesec` it is worth a shot to read the documentation anyways. It is a very powerful tool, the doc is well written and not too long (24 pages; including the doc of its affiliates `titletoc` and `titleps`) and you will most likely need it more often once in a while. Last thing regarding the spacing: you might want to add `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{20pt}`. Like that you will have less vertical spacing beneath the heading - as is the example picture of the OP, I think.

Comment: Yes, this looks much more better with `\titlespacing`. I extended my question in comment section below the second answer of my question. Could you look at this?

Comment: @EmilKob, better add an extension below your original question with an explenation of what you need in addition, so that possible other answerers have a chance to understand what the question is about entirely.

Comment: I edited my question in the way of adding my nex question.  :)

Comment: @EmilKob, usually on TeX.SX you have one question per question. The page-breaking issue seems to be not directly related to the formatting. Moreover I found it alredy answered here on this site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/start-new-chapter-on-same-page

Comment: thanks, I found this answer too, but it seems not working for me. I will work to a solution for that, when dont find the solution I will ask detailed question.